# error Policy in Apollo Client React does'nt work

Tags: graphql, apollo, handleerror

I have aproblem when test Apollo.When I try query with apollo and graphql, i want response return error and partical data, so I set property errorPolicy:'all'. But its not work. I don't no why? Help please!
Here my code:

> query {   animal {
> name
> age   },   school {
> name
> numberfd   } } `
>
> const { loading,data,error} = useQuery(GET_DASHBOARD_DATA, {
> errorPolicy:'all',
> onCompleted: (res) => {console.log("complete",res)},
> onError : (res,data) => {console.log("ERRRR",res,data)},
> })

and i want to receive:

> {
> error:[...], data:[animal:[...]] }

but its only response error.Here is Apollo's doc: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/

Answer (score -1):

`onError` type is `onError?: (error: ApolloError) => void;`. You don't have `data` inside `onError` callback.
After `useQuery` you can add:

```
console.log('data', data)
console.log('error', error)
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue with `errorPolicy: 'all'`, I only received the partial result inside `onCompleted` callback of `useQuery`, but no errors.

I created an `ErrorLink` like this:

```js
private createErrorLink = () => {
    return new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
      return forward(operation).map((response) => {
        // filter out errors you don't want to display

        const errors = filterSomeErrors(response.errors);        

        if (errors && response?.data) {
          response.data.errors = errors;
        }

        return response;
      });
    });
  };
```

Now inside my `onCompleted` callback I get my data as well as `errors`. You will have to tweak your types a bit, because seems there is no `errors` field on response.data by default.

> Mind that if you use `onError` from Apollo and return something from the link, it will **retry your request** containing errors!